# Using Reflection to get all properties of an object not implemented by an interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I want to be able use reflection to loop through the properties of an object that DO NOT implement an interface

Essentially I want to achieve the opposite of this [How do I use reflection to get properties explicitly implementing an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278997/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-get-properties-explicitly-implementing-an-interface)

The reason is I want to map objects to another object where any properties that are not defined by an interface are added instead to a List of `KeyValuePairs`.

Comment: Nothing is ever implemented *by* an interface. Do you mean you want all the properties that are *not* implementing an interface?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: nitpicking, but: do you mean to ask OP whether he wants all properties that _do not participate_ in an interface implementation?

Comment: Sorry. Yes to both above.

Comment: @StewartAlan please show some source code... what have you tried ? what exactly is not working ?

Comment: @StewartAlan: Is the interface implement explicitly or implicitly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using this example:

```
interface IFoo
{
  string A { get; set; }
}
class Foo : IFoo
{
  public string A { get; set; }
  public string B { get; set; }
}
```

Then using this code, I get only `PropertyInfo` for `B`.

```
  var fooProps = typeof(Foo).GetProperties();
  var implementedProps = typeof(Foo).GetInterfaces().SelectMany(i => i.GetProperties());
  var onlyInFoo = fooProps.Select(prop => prop.Name).Except(implementedProps.Select(prop => prop.Name)).ToArray();
  var fooPropsFiltered = fooProps.Where(x => onlyInFoo.Contains(x.Name));
```

Comment: This is assuming that the implementing property name matches the name of the property on the interface, which isn't necessarily the case.

Comment: @JonEgerton so it would be possible for `A` in `Foo` to be `C`, for example?

Comment: That's defo possible in VB.Net, not sure about C#. Might not be an issue if the OP can assume he's not working with VB.Net assemblies.

Comment: @JonEgerton If not, I can't understand how they can be different? You can't have `public string C {get; set;}` and that handles the `IFoo.A` implementation. I can't understand what you mean :)

Comment: @JonEgerton Seeing as the tag is `C#` I can't see how that is possible. I understand if this was `VB.Net` because you would have `Public Property C As String Implements IFoo.A`. That is not valid in C# as far as I am aware.

Comment: In VB you can have `Public Property C As String Implements IFoo.A` Not sure if the same can be done with C#'s syntax. Its actually useful where you implement interfaces with the same property names.

Comment: Thanks, that does exactly what I need it to.