# How to invoke a static abstract method by reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, static, abstract

I'm trying to invoke a static abstract method by reflection. Declaring static abstract methods on interfaces is a preview feature about which you can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/static-abstracts-in-interfaces).

When invoking a non-static abstract method one can simply call `TheType.GetMethod("MethodName").Invoke(null, null)` and the method is invoked, but when declaring a static abstract method in a inherited interface, it doesn't seem to become a public static method in the inheriting type. An example:

I have an interface `Entity` declaring a static abstract method `GetTableName()`:

```cs
public interface Entity
{
    public static abstract string GetTableName();
}
```

Then there are multiple types of Entities that inherit from the `Entity` interface and implement the `GetTableName` method:

```cs
static string Entity.GetTableName() => "[dbo].[SomeTable]";
```

When trying to add the `public` keyword to this implementation, an error message is given:
`The modifier 'public' is not valid for explicit interface implementation`, which I interpret as: the interface has already declared this method as public, so remove this keyword. (Is this correct?)

When trying to invoke the static abstract method with reflection on the implementing type, the method is not found and `GetMethod()` returns `null`. During debugging, I can see that the method is declared as the full qualifier of the `Entity` type, followed by the method name 'GetTableName', so I have tried to invoke in multiple ways such as:

```cs
var tableName = someType.GetMethod("GetTableName").Invoke(null, null);
var tableName = someType.GetMethod("FullQualifier.Entity.GetTableName").Invoke(null, null);
var tableName = someType.GetMethod("GetTableName", BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(null, null);
var tableName = someType.GetMethod("GetTableName", BindingFlags.Static).Invoke(null, null);
```

Sadly, all return null. Upon further debugging, the method seems to be declared as NonPublic. Still, using the NonPublic binding flag has no effect. How can one invoke the static abstract method with reflection? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/278997/5133585)

Comment: It does! I have no idea how, but adapting the answer to my situation fixed my issue. I unfortunately don't understand why this works though. Could someone explain?

Comment: @Sweeper I feel like there remains an unanswered portion of this question; why is the method nonpublic when it is declared as public?

Comment: It’s not public at the IL level because you are not allowed to access it directly through the declared type. You must access an explicit interface implementation through an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how is your code organized. Following code works fine:

For getting type, using type of implemented class.  `typeof(SomeTableEntity);`

```
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1;

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var someType = typeof(SomeTableEntity);
        var tableName = someType.GetMethod("GetTableName").Invoke(null, null);
        Console.WriteLine(tableName);
    }
}


public interface Entity
{
    public static abstract string GetTableName();
}

public class SomeTableEntity : Entity
{
    public static string GetTableName() => "[dbo].[SomeTable]";
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it makes a difference that `SomeTableEntity` is a `sealed record`?

Comment: The difference is in that the implementing method is declared as Entity.GetTableName(). I don't remember why, but VS required me to do this.

Comment: In this example `SomeTableEntity` seems to declare another `GetTableName()` method hiding `Entity.GetTableName`. I don't really know how/why cause I'd have expected the compiler would have required to implement `Entity.GetTableName()` in `SomeTableName` in a first place.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Sweeper, a look at the [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/278997/5133585) helped me solve my issue;

```cs
var getTableNameMethod = (from method
  in SomeType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
  select method
).First()!;
var tableName = getTableNameMethod.Invoke(null, null);
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea why this works, so if anyone does understand, please leave a comment.

Comment: Using `GetMethods()` with `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static` would expose all static non public methods, including all default interface static methods implementation in your class. From my understanding (I could be very wrong), though the method is `public` in interface, from class POV it is not because it is not a method of it's own. You just "`override`" it's implementation in this class, but still belong to interface "`scope`" (hence the use of `static string Entity.GetTableName()` in `SomeTableEntity`.

Comment: You could think, as I did, that using only `BindingFlags.Static` would return your method, but turn out you have to specify also it is `BindingFlags.NonPublic` usign `|` operator in order to select it. In your code I'd prefer not return `First()` because you could have several static non public methods. Maybe using `First(method => method.Name.Contains(nameof(Entity.GetTableName)))` instead. (That's still wouldn't be enough in case of method overloading. You would have to descriminate further along expected parameters signature)

Comment: *I would have prefer this issue not marked as duplicate since it deals with static abstract interface method that didn't exist in other, 15 years old, post.* My answer would have been this : `var tableName = someType.GetMethod($"{typeof(Entity).FullName}.{nameof(Entity.GetTableName)}", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).Invoke(null, null);`